# Login successful but username is None

Tags: django, authentication

I'm using User authentication to all pages. Like this:

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name='redirect_to')
def memp(request):
    ...
```

But some pages can not get user information.

In views: `request.GET.get('user') = None` and in templates: `{{user}} = None`

I cannot find the root cause of it.

Comment: both in views and in templates you just have to do `request.user` to get the logged user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a view you should be using `request.user`, does that work?

In a template, if `{{ user }}` doesn't work, make sure you are using a `RequestContext` to render the template. You should also make sure you have the `"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth"` context processor active in your `settings.py`.

Comment: I tried to request.user & request.user.is_authenticated() in my views.  then request.user = "admin"(work) request.user.is_authenticated() = guest.. what is problem?

Comment: my login url = > url(r'^accounts/login/?', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name':'acc/login.html'}),

Comment: You should consider posting another question...it's hard to understand what you're asking in the comments here. This page will answer many of your questions, though: [user authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that all the instances are supposed to be from GET? Why don't you use `request.user` in your views?